# Need to show a notice on the product page, for products in a specific category

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to show a notice on the product page, when the product belongs to a certain category. The Danish version stops and only load the half page. The Swedish version seem to work perfect?! My Magento installation doesn't show anything in the logs either.

**Is there a better way to achieve this?**

www.alldo.dk /stylish-angle-white/ Doesn't work!

www.alldo.se /stylish-angle-white/ Does work!

```
<!-- SHOW NOTICE -->    
<?php

### GET THE FIRST CATEGORY ID FOR THIS PRODUCT ###

$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

if(count($categoryIds) ){
    $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);
}

### ONLY RUN ON PRODUCT PAGES ###
if($this->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'catalog' && $this->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'product'){

    ### SHOW CORRECT NOTICE FOR EACH STORE ###
    if ( Mage::app() -> getStore() -> getCode() == 'domain_com' && $_category -> getId() == 5 ){ 
            echo 'An important notice ...';
    }

    if ( Mage::app() -> getStore() -> getCode() == 'domain_org' && $_category -> getId() == 5 ){ 
            echo 'An important notice ...';
    }

}
?>
<!-- SHOW NOTICE -->
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check more easily, if you are on Product page or not. See this code:

```
    <?php

$isProductPage = Mage::registry("current_product");
if ($isProductPage) {
    $categoryIds = Mage::registry("current_product")->getCategoryIds();
    $_categoryId = 5;
    $showNotice = false;
    if (count($categoryIds)) {
        $showNotice = in_array($_categoryId, $categoryIds);
    }

    $isProductPage = Mage::registry("current_product");
    if ($isProductPage && $showNotice) {
        echo $this->__('An important notice ...'); //With this you utilize the standard magento translator, so you don't need two separate row.
    }
}
?>
```

Then you can add to the theme a translate.csv file with your custom message for each store view. Of course if you have different theme for each store view, you can use that also.